# Appcelerator black screen on close window

Tags: button, back, appcelerator

Greetings,

I'm using appcelerator to develop some apps, but I'm encountering some problems.

Every time I close the base window, I keep getting some black screen. How do I exit the application without having to press the Android back button twice?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/38061/android-application-close-how-to